# When the vector sum of 3 co-planar forces, A, B, and C, is parallel to A, we can conclude that B and C:

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

*Option 1)*  must be equal and opposite

*Option 2)*  must have equal and opposite components perpendicular to A

*Option 3)*  must have equal and opposite components parallel to A

*Option 4)*  must have equal and opposite components perpendicular and parallel to A

I think the answer is (1) because if all 3 are acting on a point in the same plane and B and C are equal and opposite, they cancel out, then the resultant force is A, which I think can be said is parallel to A? But the answer is actually B, and I can find no explanation for this answer anywhere.
Thank you, in advance, for your time and help.

Comment: You are right that if B and C cancel exactly then the resultant force will be A. But the resultant force doesn't have to be A, it only has to be parallel to A, so we need the combination of B and C to be parallel to A...

Comment: $\left( \overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B}+\overrightarrow{C}\right) \times \overrightarrow{A}=\overrightarrow{0}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a vector in $xy$-plane
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} &= a_1\hat{i}\\
\mathbf{B} &= b_1\hat{i}+b_2\hat{j}\\
\mathbf{C} &= c_1\hat{i}+c_2\hat{j}
\end{align}

We have chosen $\mathbf{A}$ to be along $x$-axis without loss of generality.

$$\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{C}=\alpha\mathbf{A}$$
$$\Rightarrow -b_2=c_2,\ \ \ \ \ (\alpha-1)a_1=b_1+c_1$$
So using the  two conditions, We deduce
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} &= a_1\hat{i}\\
\mathbf{B} &= b_1\hat{i}+b_2\hat{j}\\
\mathbf{C} &= c_1\hat{i}-b_2\hat{j}
\end{align}
All options are wrong!

---

All the answers contain that components must be equal and opposite but consider the following example:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} &= 4\hat{i}\\
\mathbf{B} &= 2\hat{i}+\hat{j}\\
\mathbf{C} &= 3\hat{i}-\hat{j}
\end{align}
$$\sum=8\hat{i}$$
and component  of $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are not equal and opposite.

---

It might be the case that by parallel they meant equal, In that case, $\alpha=1\Rightarrow b_1=-c_1$ That means Option (A) would be correct.